# How to remove negation in if block?

Tags: go, boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

Followed the do..while pattern recommended [here](https://yourbasic.org/golang/do-while-loop/):

```
for {
    work()
    if !condition {
        break
    }
}
```

---

Below code is implementing do..while(condition) using for loop:

```
var r *s
var err error
counter := 0

for { // do..while(specificerror && < MAX && trigger_not_initiated)

    r, err = f()
    counter = counter + 1
    if !(err != nil &&
        strings.Contains(err.Error(), "specificerror") &&
        counter < MAX &&
        !IsTriggerInitiated()) {
        break
    }
}
```

---

But review team suggests to make if condition more readable by removing negation in negation(condition) in `if` statement

How to remove negation in negation(condition) for `if` statement?

Answer (score 7):

The transformation you need is called [De Morgan's Laws:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

> - not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)
> - not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B),

So if you have a statement like this:

```
if !(a && b && c) {}
```

It is equivalent to

```
if !a || !b || !c {}
```

In your example:

```
if !(err != nil &&
    strings.Contains(err.Error(), "specificerror") &&
    counter < MAX &&
    !IsTriggerInitiated()) {
    break
}
```

Translated version:

```
if err == nil ||
    !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "specificerror") ||
    counter >= MAX ||
    IsTriggerInitiated() {
    break
}
```

One thing that needs to be inspected: *short-circuit evaluation*. In a series of `&&` if an expression is evaluated to `false`, the rest will not be evaluated (we know the result is `false`).

Luckily, this will remain the same in the translated version: short-circuit evaluation will be the same, because in a series of `||` if an expression is evaluated to `true`, the rest will not be evaluated (we know the result is `true`). So when in the original form `a` is `false`, that's exactly the same case when `!a` is `true` in the transformed form.

Comment: not (A or B) ⟷ (not A) and (not B) holds in classical logic only. In constructive (ituitionistic) logic you have just not (A or B) ⟵ (not A) and (not B) which doesn't allow the translation you suggested. But I doubt that someone asking OP's question is not really interested in these finer parts of logic, so have an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

> How to remove negation in negation(condition) for if statement?

Exactly as suggested ("use `||`")

```
if !(a && b)
```

is equivalent to

```
if !a || !b
```

For more information, see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).